# Joomla mootools Ajax request always returning response text suffixed by '[]'

Tags: ajax, joomla, mootools

I am having a peculiar problem. I am trying to validate some card numbers using AJAX. Entire process goes fine and I am getting response from the script as expected. But I am not sure why all the response texts (even if it is an empty string) will show a [] suffixed to it when I alert it on my javascript. If I give an alert directly from the javascript, it shows fine. But all the responses from AJAX gives the above mentioned output.

Can anyone give me a clue why this is happening? I might have done something stupid in my code... but not able to figure out what... Any inputs will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Javascript Code:

```
var url = '" . JURI::base() . "index.php?option=<component>&view=<view>&format=raw&task=<task>';
var a = new Request({
    url: url,
    data: {
        '".JUtility::getToken()."': 1
    },
    method: 'post',
    onSuccess: function(responseText) {
        alert(responseText);
    },
    onFailure: function(xhr) {
        alert('Failed');
    }
}).send();
```

PHP Script on view.raw.php

```
<?php echo "Here"; ?>
```

This script when run, will throw the alert message as `"Here[]"`

---- RENDERED JAVASCRIPT CODE ---

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    if($('addpluspayment')) {
        $('addpluspayment').addEvent('click', function(event) {
            bbCardNum = $('bbpluscardpayment').value;
            if(bbCardNum.length <= 0) {
                alert('Número de tarjeta no válida');
                return;
            }
            totalAmountToCheck = parseFloat($('taqPaymentAmount').value);
            var url = 'http://mydomain.com/index.php?option=com_bbpayment&view=taqcart&format=raw&task=bbcheckpoints';
            var a = new Request({
                url: url,
                data: {'5df1de004436f241ef112345035bab51':1,'totalAmountToCheck':totalAmountToCheck,'bbCardNum':bbCardNum}, 
                method: 'post',
                onSuccess: function(responseText) {
                    if(responseText == 'othercategories[]') {
                        alert('Entradas encontradas en otras categorías');
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(responseText);
                    }
                },
                onFailure: function(xhr) {
                    alert('Failed');
                }
            }).send();
        });
    }
});
```

Here, the alerts - 'Número de tarjeta no válida', 'Entradas encontradas en otras categorías' and 'Failed' (which are directly thrown from the javascript) comes up without any problems.. but all responseText alerts suffix a [], even if the PHP script echos just 'Hello' (which will throw the alert as 'Hello[]')

Comment: Can you post a example of your form html? and how the response is echoed from php

Comment: Hi Sergio, thanks for your response... Let me furnish below the script details.

Javascript Code:

var url = '" . JURI::base() . "index.php?option=<component>&view=<view>&format=raw&task=<task>';
var a = new Request({
 url: url,
 data: {'".JUtility::getToken()."':1}, 
 method: 'post',
 onSuccess: function(responseText) {
  alert(responseText);
 },
 onFailure: function(xhr) {
  alert('Failed');
 }
}).send();


PHP Script on view.raw.php

<?php
echo "Here";
?>

This script when run, will throw the alert message as "Here[]"

Comment: Can you post the rendered javascript? the one you posted looks like being from the php page that generate the javascript. Post one of the html of the input also at least.

Comment: Post some more code or a live link, I don't see anything wrong with the ajax call.

Comment: @Sergio, I am sorry that I could not respond on time... I tried to put my rendered javascript code here, but it is not accepting as it is too long for the comment field. I don't know how to put the script for your reference :S

Comment: @Sujith, I see no problem with your Mootools. Can you copy that url and open it directly? paste the url and see how the `echo 'Hello';` renders. Does it have `[]` ?

Comment: @Sergio, I tried to open the URL directly and it echos with [] suffix :S So it implies that there can be something wrong with my PHP script.. right?  Let me try to look for it and will update here if I get a solution... Thank you so much for your kind advice.

Comment: @Sujith, post the PHP here so we can help if you want.

Comment: @Sergio, sorry that I cannot post the full PHP code.  My ajax request is calling just a function inside a php page, and that function just echos "Hello" and no other code (I made it like this to test).  And the alert thrown is still having [] suffixed.  Now I had taken off that section and replaced it with a form submission code and it works properly.  Thanks for all your guidance and it was really helpful to me.  Will keep in touch.. thank you once again

Comment: @Sujith, glad you got it working. If you want you can post the answer here, or maybe delete this question if it's not usefull to others. See you around!